# Consulta SQL com OR fica lenta

Tags: mysql, select, where

Tenho uma consulta que faz a busca usando:

```
WHERE pt.product_name LIKE '%termo da busca%'
```

Aí quero que a busca também procure por nome do artista e coloquei:

```
WHERE pt.product_name LIKE '%termo da busca%' OR ct.mf_name LIKE '%termo da busca%'
```

Só que aí a busca fica muito lenta, tem alguma outra forma de se fazer isso?
Acho que um dos meus problemas é porque na consulta ele consulta muitas tabelas: 8, pq pega a imagem de uma, artista de outra, nome de outra....

Essa é a consulta toda

```
SELECT pt.virtuemart_product_id, pt.product_name as nome, pt.slug as musica, ct.mf_name, cantor.virtuemart_product_id,
pc.virtuemart_product_id, pc.virtuemart_category_id,
p.virtuemart_product_id, p.product_special,
cpt.virtuemart_category_id, cpt.slug as link,
pm.virtuemart_product_id, pm.virtuemart_media_id,
m.virtuemart_media_id, m.file_url as foto
FROM euk_virtuemart_products_pt_pt pt, euk_virtuemart_product_categories pc, euk_virtuemart_products p, euk_virtuemart_categories_pt_pt cpt, euk_virtuemart_product_medias pm, euk_virtuemart_medias m, euk_virtuemart_manufacturers_pt_pt ct, euk_virtuemart_product_manufacturers cantor
WHERE pt.virtuemart_product_id = pc.virtuemart_product_id
AND pt.virtuemart_product_id = p.virtuemart_product_id
AND pc.virtuemart_category_id = cpt.virtuemart_category_id
AND pm.virtuemart_product_id = pt.virtuemart_product_id
AND m.virtuemart_media_id = pm.virtuemart_media_id
AND ct.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = cantor.virtuemart_product_id
AND p.product_special = 0
AND ct.mf_name LIKE '%quero%' OR pt.product_name LIKE '%quero%'
GROUP BY pt.virtuemart_product_id
ORDER BY p.created_on DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você fizer um `UNION` pode ser que melhore:

```
(SELECT pt.virtuemart_product_id, pt.product_name as nome, pt.slug as musica, ct.mf_name, cantor.virtuemart_product_id,
pc.virtuemart_product_id, pc.virtuemart_category_id,
p.virtuemart_product_id, p.product_special,
cpt.virtuemart_category_id, cpt.slug as link,
pm.virtuemart_product_id, pm.virtuemart_media_id,
m.virtuemart_media_id, m.file_url as foto
FROM euk_virtuemart_products_pt_pt pt, euk_virtuemart_product_categories pc, euk_virtuemart_products p, euk_virtuemart_categories_pt_pt cpt, euk_virtuemart_product_medias pm, euk_virtuemart_medias m, euk_virtuemart_manufacturers_pt_pt ct, euk_virtuemart_product_manufacturers cantor
WHERE pt.virtuemart_product_id = pc.virtuemart_product_id
AND pt.virtuemart_product_id = p.virtuemart_product_id
AND pc.virtuemart_category_id = cpt.virtuemart_category_id
AND pm.virtuemart_product_id = pt.virtuemart_product_id
AND m.virtuemart_media_id = pm.virtuemart_media_id
AND ct.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = cantor.virtuemart_product_id
AND p.product_special = 0
AND ct.mf_name LIKE '%quero%'
GROUP BY pt.virtuemart_product_id
ORDER BY p.created_on DESC
LIMIT 30)
UNION
(SELECT pt.virtuemart_product_id, pt.product_name as nome, pt.slug as musica, ct.mf_name, cantor.virtuemart_product_id,
pc.virtuemart_product_id, pc.virtuemart_category_id,
p.virtuemart_product_id, p.product_special,
cpt.virtuemart_category_id, cpt.slug as link,
pm.virtuemart_product_id, pm.virtuemart_media_id,
m.virtuemart_media_id, m.file_url as foto
FROM euk_virtuemart_products_pt_pt pt, euk_virtuemart_product_categories pc, euk_virtuemart_products p, euk_virtuemart_categories_pt_pt cpt, euk_virtuemart_product_medias pm, euk_virtuemart_medias m, euk_virtuemart_manufacturers_pt_pt ct, euk_virtuemart_product_manufacturers cantor
WHERE pt.virtuemart_product_id = pc.virtuemart_product_id
AND pt.virtuemart_product_id = p.virtuemart_product_id
AND pc.virtuemart_category_id = cpt.virtuemart_category_id
AND pm.virtuemart_product_id = pt.virtuemart_product_id
AND m.virtuemart_media_id = pm.virtuemart_media_id
AND ct.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = cantor.virtuemart_product_id
AND p.product_special = 0
AND pt.product_name LIKE '%quero%'
GROUP BY pt.virtuemart_product_id
ORDER BY p.created_on DESC
LIMIT 30)
```

Comment: perfeito deu certo, só pra eu entender, oq vc fez foi duplicar as consultas e em uma busca pela musica e a outra pelo artista e depois une?

Comment: Exatamente isso